# inserting a node into SQL 2008 xml datatype... checking if it exists first

Tags: sql, xml, database, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am reading through a plethora of articles at the moment to try to assist me.. just seems so many options and cannot seem to find a clean solution.. it probably is very basic so apologies in advance!

So I have an XML field in SQL 2008.  It basically contains something like:

`<root><id>1</id><id>4</id></root>`   and so on...

What I am hoping to do is pass a param in to a proc to insert an  value IF it doesn't exist..

So rather than read the xml first and do this within say .NET code, is there a clean way of doing this within a stored proc/t-sql ???

Any help appreciated!  I am sure this is a fairly common one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using the [value()](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2007/06/shredding-xml-in-sql-server-2005.html) method:

```
DECLARE 
  @x xml, 
  @param int

SET @x = '<root><id>1</id><id>2</id><id>3</id></root>'
SET @param = 1

IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM @x.nodes('/root/id') n(x) WHERE x.value('.','int') = @param
) 
PRINT 'Insert'
ELSE 
PRINT 'Return'
```

Comment: Wow, really excellent clear answers.. thank you!!  just having a look now.. but many thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.exist()` XQuery function on your XML to find out if a given node exists or not.

Check out [An Overview of XML Support in SQL Server 2005](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050803.htm) - it's a great article on how to use the various XQuery functions available. Just after the middle of that page, you'll find this section:

> **Using the exist Method**
>
> The exist method takes an XPath
>   expression that selects a single node
>   within the XML document, and returns
>   either True (bit value 1) if the node
>   exists or False (bit value 0) if it
>   does not. If the source column is a
>   typed xml column (in which case you
>   must declare the namespace in your
>   query), and the element contains null,
>   the method returns NULL instead. So
>   the XQuery:

```
SELECT MyXml.exist('(/root/product[@id="304"])[1]' FROM MyTable
```

> will return True if there is a product
>   with the id value "304" (a product
>   element with the attribute id="304"),
>   or False if not. You can also use the
>   exist method in the WHERE clause of a
>   SQL statement:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM MyTable
WHERE MyXml.exist('(/root/product[@id="304"])[1]') = 1
```

Comment: Thank you! as mentioned to the other answer, really many thanks for such a complete response.  Will check into the answers now and respond.  Thanks!!!